# How do I get NPM commands to run properly in Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eclipse, npm, terminal

I have a usable workflow that I want to make better.  I'm building a JS library, and the way I am executing smoke tests on code is by using webpack to package the library and write it to a file that is included in an HTML file for viewing the effects of the code.

To do this, I make changes to the file in Eclipse, save it, then I must leave Leave eclipse and go to Terminal to run "npm run buildInbrowser" to execute "webpack --config inbrowser.config.js".

The configuration works perfect with regards to webpack, the configuration, and the npm setup, but when I try to configure eclipse to run those commands, it brings up an error: "env: node: No such file or directory"  I've attached screenshots of my launch NPM configuration.

My system is MacOSX Catalina using Nodeclipse, npm v9.3.1 and node 16.18.0.

Again, there is no issue with me running these commands in terminal, but they won't run through node.  This makes me think it's something simple that I overlooked.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why did you include a $ in your environment variable's name?

Comment: Well, that did the trick!  I replaced "$PATH" with "PATH" and it ran fine.  Thank you kind sir!  I'll write it up in here so it can be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

As nitind pointed out, I had incorrect syntax on the PATH variable for eclipse, which was causing the problem. Also noted is that Eclipse did not populate my path variable by default, so i did have to manually enter it in.  See the screen shot for the fix.

[image]